# Ninject Serilization error when calling new StandardKernel

Tags: c#, ninject

When I try to call

```
 var ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
```

I get the below error. I can successfully use ninject with constructor injection. I only get this error when I try to grab a service by hand.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type
> 'Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver' in assembly
> 'Ninject.Web.WebApi, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' is not marked as
> serializable.","ExceptionType":"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException","StackTrace":"
> at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName,
> String typeName)\r\n   at
> Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable`1 filenames, Predicate`1 filter)\r\n   at
> Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 filenames)\r\n   at Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 patterns)\r\n
> at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 filePatterns)\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules)\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)\r\n   at Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)\r\n   at Controllers.Controllers.TagController.GetTags(TagEnum tagType) in C:\\Users\\george\\Desktop\\NewScp\\SCP\\UI\\Controllers\\TagController.cs:line 39\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
> where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @scottlafoy no, I pulled all of ninject out and went with simple injector